# Elastic Search Query: Query Whole Words Only

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I've recently started using Elastic Search and I can't seem to make it search for WHOLE WORDS ONLY.

Ex:

> Input: abc
>
> Match: abc, abc d, e abc, ...
>
> Not match: abcd, emabc, ...

I have tried using following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "default_field": "keywords.alias",
            "query": "abc"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "facets": {}
}
```

But nothing seems to work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you use [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) for analyzing fields at index time, which will split data into words. Then you just need to use [Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) (or more flexible query: [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), which support multi fields, wildcard searching...) to query data:

```
{
  "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "keywords.alias" : {
            "query" : "abc"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I added like this "index": "not_analyzed", then I got correct result.

Comment: if your input data is ID, or something like that, then it fine. But if your input is like "abc, def 123" (a phrase), then it will not worked. `not_analyzed` mean to keep the input as it. Hope it clear for you.